# Recommended buffer and rebuffer duration of data for ExoPlayer instance and the impact of changing those

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

The ExoPlayer sample comes with the following defaults:

`mPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, 1000, 5000);`

Where 1000 is `minBufferMs` and 5000 is `minRebufferMs`. From the documentation:

> **minBufferMs** - A minimum duration of data that must be buffered for
> playback to start or resume following a user action such as a seek.
>
> **minRebufferMs** - A minimum duration of data that must be buffered for
> playback to resume after a player invoked rebuffer (i.e. a rebuffer
> that occurs due to buffer depletion, and not due to a user action such
> as starting playback or seeking).

These seem like reasonable defaults but are probably related to the average video length the player is built for? In my app an average video is about 24s, however, there are instances where a video can be 1 second or <6s. I think these default values are causing me some issues with those edge case videos (those videos are not playing as their duration is < minBuff or minRebuff after the first buff) so I'm thinking of changing them.

The question is, what's the recommended values and what is the impact of setting those two values to, say, 500 and 2000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are not really related to the total length of the video - they are to do with the amount you want to buffer to try to ensure playback without having to pause the video while it buffers more video.

If your video is extremely short, as in your 1 second example, then this is probably an edge case where it might be worth experimenting with some different values.

I think any recommended values will be no more than recommendations, though, and the defaults above do not seem unreasonable. You could experiment with changing the values but the problem is that your results will reflect the network, CPU load etc conditions that were present during your test.

Adaptive bit rate videos will also muddy the water a little as the player will switch between bit rates also to try to find the highest quality bit rate for the current network conditions. Again, your 1 second duration videos are an edge case for which adaptive bit rate videos probably do not make a lot of sense, unless they are part of a continuous stream of videos and you want to be able to keep the bit rate similar for all.